# Outsourcing projects: is there a threshold on how much I can deduct from taxes (IRS)?

Tags: usa, outsourcing, subcontracting

Suppose that:

I have a $10000 project. I subcontract the entire project to a subcontractor and pays that person $9999. This means my net gain (or profit) is $1.

If I submit that info to the IRS when doing taxes, will that trigger an audit?

Is there a money threshold on how much my budget is when subcontracting and/or how much I can deduct subcontracting/outsourcing costs from the gross income (which would be $10000 in this case)?

Comment: If you don't have at least a 30% gross margin on subcontracting, it is not likely that you are making a profit for even taking on that project. Your sales and marketing time can chew up that much.

Comment: But your turnover is 10k.  So there's Sales Tax (VAT) to consider.